# rewrite mod not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Tried several solutions from the web, bud didn't work for me. Therefore, here is my situation and I'd be really glad if someone can help me.

This is my httpd.conf file main info for the issue:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is my .htaccess info:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /post.php?bID=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The goal was to rewrite

from: `www.site.com/post.php?bID=7&title=blog-title`
to: `www.site.com/blog7/blog-title`

However it is not working (page is loaded normally but url is not modified)! I generated the rewrite rule through http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php so it should be ok.

---

The strange thing is that while trying other rules like hiding php extension it works fine, so the .htaccess rules are apparently working.

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Does anyone has any guess?

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "not working" ? What kind of error do you got? What happened in apache error.log ?

Comment: btw, http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is good place for testing .htaccess

Comment: thanks for the tip! @hjpotter92 answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /post.php\?bID=(\d+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /post.php?bID=$1&title=$2 [NE,L]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked this way, do you know the reason why it wasn't work with my rewrite rule? also, for next rules do I need to repeat the rewritecond? cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your rules, try to disable mod_negotiation [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews):

```
Options -Multiviews
```

before using any RewriteRule.